# Creating a stub login page

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I am working on an application where the authentication is done using LDAP. I don't have LDAP setup at local machine and I can't setup it as well due to some reasons.

How can i create a stub login page where i just enter the user name and some arbit password and the user gets authenticated. After the authentication a session should be created and also the calls like:

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

should return me the username entered on the login page.

I have java/J2EE based application which is based on spring, hibernate (if this helps)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ApacheDS which not required any installation and enable an embedded LDAP server locally .

We use this scenario for Integration tests and developement mode .

Here is a config with spring security provider configuration :

```
<ldap-server ldif="classpath:ldap-users.ldif" port="33389" root="dc=yourCompany,dc=com" />

<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <beans:property name="url" value="ldaps://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=yourCompany,dc=com"/>
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="cn=Manager,cn=Users"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="secret"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapTemplate" class ="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate" >
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

the only difference between this file and the productionfile that point to the real LDAP server is this config line :

```
<ldap-server ldif="classpath:ldap-users.ldif" port="33389" root="dc=yourCompany,dc=com" />
```

And we provide a `ldap-user.ldif` in the classpath which define LDAP schema (Oranizations...) and populate some users for testing .

And finally add this to your dependencies :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
                <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5</version>
            </dependency>
```

if you are not using Maven just download the jar and put it your classpath .

Hope it's Help .

Answer (score -1):

Even if you don't check the password, you do need to match the entered name with the userid to be authenticated. For that you need to query through the records, which essentially means setting up LDAP on your local system.

If you can't do that, try [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) or some other alternative.

Comment: I wish to stub the authentication process. Can't setup LDAP on my local machine.

Comment: I see. So replace the function where you authenticate with some pre-defined return values (stub users).

Comment: Just returning some values won't serve the purpose. It won't create a new request and session and I won't get username from request.getUserPrincipal().getName(). Downvoted as it is nowhere near the answer. I had already written in the question that I can't setup LDAP, setting up OpenLDAP instead is not a solution!.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, to get request.getUserPrincipal( is a command from javax.servlet.http so you need to have some kind of server set up.

Comment: Yes, to get user from request, a servlet container is obv. I didn't mentioned that obv. thing. Anyways, my application is deployed on Weblogic server.